Making small acrylic parts
I'm wanting to make some small-ish parts from 4mm acrylic, however I'm a bit apprehensive due to the tapered design and the radii.

I have a selection of power tools in my arsenal, however a bandsaw isn't available. I do have a tablesaw, router, sander etc.
I think this is a 2 part question (sorry!):

Would I risk cracking with this design? I'm aware that I might need to re-think the outer radii due to the "holes should be at least 1.5x the thickness away from the edge" rule.
Can I use my sander to make the radii like you would typically see done with wood?


Acrylic cuts very well with infrared laser. With 4 mm thick you'll get some tapering of the edges each side of the focal plane. If that's tolerable then I recommend looking for someone in your area that could do the job. They'll typically need a DXF or SVG file but for something this simple could draw it for you very quickly. Acrylic is brittle and stress cracking is a problem. I'd be concerned about the M4 threaded hole.

Drill and tap the holes before you shape the final outline.

what is preventing you from trying to make one? ... ask questions after

practice on scrap wood ... create a jig to make the outside radius ... the jig would have a 4 mm pin ... drill 4 mm hole in the piece ... place on jig ... swivel while sanding ... do same with the 8 mm end ... add end stops to the jig to prevent swiveling part too far

@jsotola limited amount of material (and budget) means I've been a bit apprehensive to just give it a go thus far. I think I was thinking around the same lines as you for the actual process :-)

cut the piece from cardboard and then use it to figure out what the jig should look like ... test it using thin plywood

Keep in mind that there are 2 types of acrylic sheet commonly available. Extruded and cast. Extruded acrylic is cheaper and looks the same, but it has high internal stresses and cracks very easily. Cast is more expensive but less brittle. Extruded is most common.

If you're going to make the part by hand anyway I recommend you use a different plastic. PVC or polycarbonate for example.

In common room temperatures acrylic is brittle. It cracks easily if one tries to make a hole with an usual well sharpened drill bit. A worn drill bit works better. That's because acrylic loses its brittleness when warmed. In 100 degrees centigrade acrylic is plastic.
I do not know which stresses you are going to apply to your parts when they are in use. But you can avoid breaking them before they are fully fabricated. Try to make your parts in higher temperature. For example have a properly adjusted and aimed hot air blower. Keep it ON when you drill or make threads and a while before to warm the tools, too.
Experiments are a must!
